# Relations in Rails 4.2: 1-to-many or two 1-to-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

**How I would describe it should work:**

A `User` **Alice** can initiate an `Exchange` with another `User` **Bob**. So Alice is the *initiating user* of this `Exchange`, and Bob is the *requested user*.

A `User` can have many `Exchange`s.

An `Exchange` has one `initiating_user` and one `requested_user`.
I am unsure if this is a 1-to-1 or 1-to-many relationship, since both are of `User`, but are not addressed with the same name.

An `Exchange` has exactly two `Rating`s, but the same problem as before applies. I do not know if this is a 1-to-1 or 1-to-many relationship.
Each one of `initiating_user` and `requested_user` can make a `Rating`.
Which is then the `initiating_user_rating` or `requested_user_rating` respectively.

A `Rating` belongs to exactly one `Exchange`.

**My Problem:**

I am almost certain that there is a much simpler approach than what I am using now, probably just with use of `ActiveRecord` relations.
It works at the moment, but I am not happy with it.

So I guess my questions are:

- Are those `initiating_user`/`requested_user` and `initiating_user_rating`/`requested_user_rating` relations each 1-to-many
  or two 1-to-1?
- Is there a better way to set up the relations for this constellation?
- If not, how do I get the structure to be less hacky and more rails-y?

**Not-really-UML:**

[image: UML of how it should work]

**Code:**

In `app/models/user.rb`

```
# Exchanges
has_many :initiated_exchanges, class_name: "Exchange",
                               foreign_key: "init_user_id"
has_many :requested_exchanges, class_name: "Exchange",
                               foreign_key: "req_user_id"
# Ratings
has_many :init_user_ratings, through: :initiated_exchanges
has_many :req_user_ratings, through: :requested_exchanges
```

And in `app/models/exchange.rb`

```
# Users
belongs_to :init_user, class_name: "User",
                       foreign_key: "init_user_id"
belongs_to :req_user, class_name: "User",
                      foreign_key: "req_user_id"
# Ratings
belongs_to :init_user_rating, class_name: "Rating",
                              foreign_key: "init_user_rating_id"
belongs_to :req_user_rating, class_name: "Rating",
                             foreign_key: "req_user_rating_id"
```

In `app/models/rating.rb`

```
def exchange
  Exchange.find_by("init_user_rating_id=? or req_user_rating_id=?", id, id)
end
```

From `app/db/schema.rb`

```
create_table "exchanges", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "init_user_id",        null: false
  t.integer  "req_user_id",         null: false
  t.integer  "init_user_rating_id"
  t.integer  "req_user_rating_id"

  t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
end

create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "rating"
  t.text     "text",                limit: 1000

  t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
end
```